# Why is console non-standard?

Tags: javascript

Looking at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log), you can find this message:

> **Non-standard**
>
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
> track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
> work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
> implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Obviously, `console` isn't meant for production, and I presume that it is used by a *helluvalot* of people, **so why hasn't it be made a standard or proposed as a standard?** It isn't related to the DOM, but couldn't it be made a feature of ECMAScript? It seems that host environments may always provide a way to output something into a console, or decide to ignore it, so I wouldn't see the harm in it being made a standard.

Comment: You could ask the people who work on the standard: https://esdiscuss.org.

Comment: console is a debugging tool ie: not meant for the production site. I have seen console.debug() crash ie browsers but not console.log(). It would be bad practice to keep them in the production code, but I agree making them a standard would be a good idea.

Comment: In general, the standards committee tend make the standard reflect real-world browser implementations (and in the future maybe stuff from node.js as well). Since console.log is still problematic for IE it's not added to the standard. If MS Edge implements console.log the same way as the rest of the browser makers we'll probably see it standardized in ES7 or html6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same question was asked [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-script-coord/2013JanMar/0152.html), where you can read the full messaging thread for all arguments made by supporters and *non-supporters* of Console API standardization.

In brief, there are proposals to standardize the Console API, like [this one](https://github.com/DeveloperToolsWG/console-object)  (which is initiated by the guy who asked the question). It also contains useful information about other standardization (documentation) efforts.

And regarding your statement:

> Obviously, console isn't meant for production...

Maybe it is not meant for production, but there are cases where it's useful in production, like providing tips and detailed errors for professional users. For example, Facebook uses Console API to print this cautionary banner.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I merely speculate - it's partly a problem due to backwards compatibility, but also the fact that an implementation of the `log` method may do different things for different parameters to cater to various needs of the browser designers, thus rendering it non-standard.

I don't know if you've ever seen this method -

```
if(window.console && console.log) {
    console.log('your message');
}
```

A followup question may be, how can we check for the presence of support inside the `log` method parameters if it ever turned out we needed to offer standard support for this method.

Comment: Using the cconditional statement is always best practice. Good that someone posted it even if it is production or debugging